# Scheduler is using previous version of Apex batch

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

**[Step to Reproduce]**

1. Create a new Apex Batch.
2. Set a Scheduler for the Apex Batch.
3. Update the Apex Batch.

=> Once the scheduler runs, the scheduler still using previous versions of Apex Batch. The process is not update.

**[Workaround]**
Once I delete the Scheduler & recreate it, the scheduler will use the updated version of Apex Batch.

**[Question]**
Does anyone have same issue? Do we always need to update the scheduler after updating Apex Batch ?

Comment: From my personal experience, once the job is scheduled, the class 'version' is fixed. But next time it is scheduled it will use the current version. This means that after the class update, the first scheduled run should be with the old version and the next run will be with the current.

Comment: Thank you Damecek, 
so, every time I update the Apex batch, I need to re-create the scheduler if we want to use the latest Apex 'version' right ?

Comment: No you just need to wait for the next next run.

Comment: 1. Deployed updated class
2. class run according to schedule (old version)
3. class run according to schedule (current version)

Answer (score 3):

A possible reason for this is that your scheduler execute() is coded incorrectly

### Correct

```
public class MySchedulable implements System.Schedulable {
  public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
     Database.execute(new MyBatchable(args),200);
  }
}
```

### Incorrect

```
public class MySchedulable implements System.Schedulable {
  MyBatchable bc = new MyBatchable(args);

  public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
     Database.execute(bc,200);
  }
```

Why is this incorrect? Because the batchable object is created when the schedulable is first scheduled (i.e. its constructor is invoked) and then serialized for later use on the next scheduled runtime. Thus, changes to your batchable class are never "picked up" by each execution of the schedulable's `execute()`

Comment: This looks like the answer. It boils down to the fact that the scheduled instance of the apex class doesn't change if you modify the class. The suggestion to implement both `System.Schedulable` and `Database.Batchable` does not solve the issue by the way (I like this approach, but it's not really relevant to this error).

Comment: @rael_kid - i got carried away; deleted the irrelevant part of the answer

Comment: @cropredy, thank  you for the answer. But It seems my code is written in the Correct way; having new inside the execute method.

Comment: please use [edit] in the OP and show your schedulable class